# Connecting to WCF webservices using JSON on Android

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

Recently i am developing Android applications
what i wanted to do is consume a web services
from .net WCF into my application

Here is my Client Code

```
import java.io.InputStream;<br>
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;<br>
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;<br>
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;<br>
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;<br>
import org.json.JSONObject;<br>

import android.R.string;<br>
import android.os.Bundle;<br>
import android.app.Activity;<br>
import android.view.Menu;<br>
import android.view.View;<br>
import android.widget.TextView;<br>


public class MyPamIndex extends Activity {

    private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://172.30.2.95:9000/JSON/MyPam.svc";
    private TextView NabVals;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_pam_index);


            NabVals = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
    public void OnRefreshClick(View button)
    {
         try {
             // Send GET request to <service>/GetVehicle/<plate>
             DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/ProductID/" + "1");

             request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
             HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

             // Read response data into buffer
             char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
             InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
             InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
             reader.read(buffer);
             stream.close();

             JSONObject vehicle = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
             NabVals.setText(vehicle.getString("NabValue"));
             // Populate text fields


         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

         }
    }
```

when i run the apps it have an error
in 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
i have search the entire forum but found nothing
i already add my android manifest file but still does not working
please help me

this is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.core.mypam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="anroid.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.core.mypam.MyPamIndex"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

"http://172.30.2.95:9000" is not my machine IP but its located on other PC within same LAN
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a network request on the UI thread. That is no longer allowed and, and will raise an exception. You need to move your code into an AsyncTask. Google `NetworkOnMain` for a plethora of examples.

Comment: i have move it to  AsyncTask but it gives me Connection to "http://172.30.2.95:9000" refused I've open the firewall port still have no luck

Comment: First off, check that your device can access the server, by typing the service URL into the device's browser. If that doesn't work, you'll need to trouble shoot your network. If it does work, keep checking your app. Did you get the INTERNET permission?